# Intercepting the back button

Tags: android, function

I'm writing an application which will have two Activities, when the user presses the back button on the second activity a dialog should pop up asking the user to confirm the action. So how do I intercept this? I seriously doubt about this coz the backstack is a part of the OS itself. Has anyone found a workaround?

Comment: Think hard about doing this.  This is non-standard Android behavior and might annoy your users.  Are you trying to avoid them losing unsaved data?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

In an activity you can just override

> onBackPressed()

edit: that is api lvl 5+  :/  for 4 and below you gotta override onKeyDown()

Comment: What about Fragments?

Comment: Activity onBackPressed function wont be called when dialog fragment is stacked over it.

Comment: This has been deprecated for a long time. You should use the `onBackPressedDispatcher`

Answer (score 12):

Simply override the `onKeyDown(int, KeyEvent)` method in your activity and look for the back button. Return `true` so that the event is consumed.

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        //Do something here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: +1, I've done this before and it definitely works although when I used it, it was before I understood the notion of multiple activities...

Comment: //Do somethings here (I'm trying to display a toast for my test code) 
is not working for me. And when I press the back button nothing happens.

Comment: My mistake, I didn't call Toast.show().
Working code. Thanx @skorulis

Answer (score 6):

By [the docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-custom-back#kotlin), do not use `onBackPressed` if you can. Now is recommended using `onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {}`. There's a Fragment example:

```
class MyFragment : Fragment() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        // This callback will only be called when MyFragment is at least Started.
        val callback = requireActivity().onBackPressedDispatcher.addCallback(this) {
            // Handle the back button event
        }

        // The callback can be enabled or disabled here or in the lambda
    }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 5):

As schwiz pointed out, you'll want to override the `onBackPressed()` method in your activity class (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed()).

I just wanted to add that if you did want to at some stage continue with or access the standard the back operation (after say, displaying a dialog), then you simply call `super.onBackPressed()` or `ActivityName.super.onBackPressed()` from anywhere in the Activity.