# Override android hardware back button functionality

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Can we override hardware back button functionality. I am bit confused about this kindly help me.

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614849/intercepting-the-back-button

Comment: There are many duplicate questions

Comment: Since the ways have been provided in others' answers, I just want to say one thing: pay attention to the official document: "Don't take over the Back button unless you absolutely need to" https://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/activity_task_design.html since it breaks the user experience of the whole system.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
@Override public void onBackPressed(){
  //do your stuff here
}
```

if anything related to particular key then you can go for this:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.Any_Key_Code) {
        //your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 9):

You can also override [`onBackPressed()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onBackPressed%28%29):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    //Your action
}
```

Answer (score 2):

see this

```
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "back button pressed",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        // do your stuff here
        return true;
    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    //  Action to be performed 
    super.onBackPressed(); 
}
```