# How to switch from an activity to another designated one when the device back button is pressed?

Tags: android, android-activity

I am developing an app that is currently consists of 4 activities. What I want is, while I am for an example, accessing activity number 3, when I press the back button of the device, I want to be directed to activity number 1 and not to the immediate preceding activity. Any suggestions to achieve this?

Comment: override the hardware back button and write your intent code there.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intercepting the back button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614849/intercepting-the-back-button)

Comment: why my question is downvoted???i have searched google and did not find what iam looking for??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

override it in that one Activity with

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
     // code here to show your new activity
     Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,MynextActivity.class);
     startActivity(i);
     super.onBackPressed();  // optional depending on your needs
}
```

don't put this code in any other Activity

Comment: Why??What happened??This is the code for his question..Why is my answer being downvoted??? @RichardLeMesurier

Comment: Changed downvote to upvote. I'm sure you agree that this is a better answer than your first one.

Comment: Well..Yess..:) Thankypu @RichardLeMesurier

Answer (score 0):

You can intercept android back button event by overriding `onBackPressed()` method and do whatever you need (For example start Activity1)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code:-

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed()
{
    startActivity(new Intent(ThisActivity.this, WhereYouGoActivity.class));
    finish();

}
```

Comment: perhaps slightly safer to call `super.onBackPressed()` instead of `finish()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in activity B

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) 
{
    if(keyCode==KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)
    {
       //use intent to call activity A

    }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);

}
```

Comment: this is not appropriate for newer API versions - better to use accepted answer by @Lal