# Android Soft Button and Hardware Button

Tags: android

I want to create an app that is not usable by the user  but performs some functionality outside the app, the app just run in the foreground and listen to the press of android hardware/software buttons, the likes of Power button, home button, volume up and down. It triggers a call when for instance, the volume up button is pressed down for 5 secs and notification appears.

I have checked solutions like this

[Intercepting the back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3614849/intercepting-the-back-button)

[How to override the behavior of the volume buttons in an Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367484/how-to-override-the-behavior-of-the-volume-buttons-in-an-android-application)

But this solutions have something to do with the user accessing the app directly, i mean to perform this functionalities you have to be on the app which i don't want.

The app was suppose to be run on a smart watch which runs android OS. I was thinking if i can perform this on android phone, it should be easier on the smart watch.

Note:

The App is for targeted users, who will be trained to understand that behavior.